# IOS UIScrollview not working on 3.5 inch screen

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am developing an application that will work on all IOS devices, I am using storyboards for the Ipad and Iphone layouts.

One of my ViewControllers (lets call it an 'about' screen) contains a scrollview, this scrollview has a combination of labels, buttons and textviews contained within it. I have added contraints to this scrollview for center X alignment and center Y alignment

In the viewDidAppear function in my 'About' controller class, i have set the content size depending on device, set the scrollview frame size and set scroll as enabled

```
-(void) viewDidAppear: (BOOL)animated
{
    UIScrollView *scroller = (UIScrollView *)self.ScrollableView;

    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdionIpad)
        [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 770)];
    else
        [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 1000)];

    [scroller setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
}
```

This works fine on all the Emulator devices (IPhone 4 portrait, IPad portait and landscape, IPad retina portrait and landscape) except the 3.5 inch IPhone, the code above does still get called when running on 3.5 inch device, but I am unable to scroll this view.

Here is a screenshot of my view controller:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to implement UIScrollViewDelegate in you ViewController and see if `- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` is called on 3,5" display.

Comment: that doesn't get called on any device, I added `<UIScrollViewDelegate>` to my about.h file and tried the function you mentioned as well as `scrollViewDidScrollToTop` and `scrollViewDidLoad`, none of these are being called

Comment: May be you have forgotten to set `self.ScrollableView.delegate = self;` in `initWithNibName:bundle:` or to link delegate of UIScrollView to File's Owner in InterfaceBuilder?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to set the delegate to self. Now `scrollviewDidScroll` is called when running any emulator, but the `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` is called from all emulators except from the 3.5" display

Comment: That looks strange.. May be you have some other UIView objects over your UIScrollView?

Comment: i have updated question with screenshot of the UIView

Comment: @ArthurGrishin does everything look ok in the ViewController?

Comment: As for me everything looks ok. Have you tried on real 3.5" device, not emulator? Same bug?

Comment: unfortunately, i don't have a device to try it on